# How filter javsScript array with multiple parameters

Tags: javascript, angular

How to filter data with multiple parameters ?
I want to use multiple values in my filter, and combine them with `and` condition.
As you see in image, lets suppose that I type `PQR` in `Organization` and `Mond` in `Sales Person` meaning that I only want that record in which `Organization` is `PQR` and `Sales Person` is `Mond`.

i.e to combine these condition, but the problem I'm getting is that If I combine these condition while other inputs `(filters)` are blank, I doesn't returns any data.
My code works perfectly in case of `OR` condition, in which any of the condition matches. How do I achieve the same type of output by combining the above query
Here is my code file and `executeFilters()` is the function that I'm trying

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource } from '@angular/material/table';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { MatPaginator } from '@angular/material/paginator';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
import { CollectionReportService } from '../../../../../app/services/reportServices/collection-report.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-collections-report',
  templateUrl: './collections-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./collections-report.component.scss']
})
export class CollectionsReportComponent implements OnInit {
  dataArrived = false;
  // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['date', 'invoice', 'organization', 'customer', 'salesPerson', 'authorizingOfficer', 'item', 'terms', 'ageing', 'quantity', 'price', 'amount', 'dueAmount'];
  footerColumns: string[] = ['amount', 'dueAmount'];
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true }) paginator: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort: MatSort;
  dataSource: any;
  organizationFilter;
  customerFilter;
  salesPersonFilter;
  authorizingOfficerFilter;
  itemFilter;
  constructor(
    private router: Router,
    private collectionReportService: CollectionReportService
  ) { }
  reports = [
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'ABC', customer: 'Kevin', salesPerson: 'KEN', authorizingOfficer: 'Ayub', item: 'Jiko', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'DEF', customer: 'Lorem', salesPerson: 'Brown', authorizingOfficer: 'Wah', item: 'Okoa', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'GHI', customer: 'Ipsum', salesPerson: 'Red', authorizingOfficer: 'IT', item: 'Mishi', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'JKL', customer: 'Some', salesPerson: 'Mister', authorizingOfficer: 'Intel', item: 'Chilli', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'MNO', customer: 'Frio', salesPerson: 'Kevi', authorizingOfficer: 'Red', item: 'Hitachi', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'PQR', customer: 'Litm', salesPerson: 'Bang', authorizingOfficer: 'Mond', item: 'Hari', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'STU', customer: 'Nats', salesPerson: 'Elite', authorizingOfficer: 'Amd', item: 'Kara', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'VWX', customer: 'Doda', salesPerson: 'Sniper', authorizingOfficer: 'Great', item: 'Yoko', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'XYZ', customer: 'Hima', salesPerson: 'Uni', authorizingOfficer: 'Silver', item: 'Hama', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'Foo', customer: 'Imk', salesPerson: 'Ten', authorizingOfficer: 'Some', item: 'Spoon', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
    { date: '10 - Oct', invoice: '1009', organization: 'Bar', customer: 'Tyw', salesPerson: 'Ben', authorizingOfficer: 'Other', item: 'Jiko Okoa', terms: '3', ageing: '4', quantity: '1', price: '3990.00', amount: 3990.00, dueAmount: 1330.00 },
  ];



  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reports);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
    this.collectionReportService.getReport().subscribe(resp => console.log('Response of collectionReport: ', resp), error => console.log('Error occured while fetching report: ', error));
  }

  applyFilter(filterValue: string): void {
    this.dataSource.filter = filterValue.trim().toLowerCase();
  }
  getTotalAmount(): number {
    return this.reports.map(r => r.amount).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  }
  getTotalAmountDue(): number {
    return this.reports.map(r => r.dueAmount).reduce((acc, value) => acc + value, 0);
  }
  exportCSV(): void {
    alert('Export function called');
  }

  executeFilters(): void {
    console.log('Organization: ', this.organizationFilter, 'Customer: ', this.customerFilter, 'Sales Person: ',
      this.salesPersonFilter, 'Authorizing Officer: ', this.authorizingOfficerFilter, 'Item: ', this.itemFilter);

    const filteredReport = this.reports.filter(report => report.organization === this.organizationFilter ||
      report.customer === this.customerFilter || report.salesPerson === this.salesPersonFilter || report.item === this.itemFilter ||
      report.authorizingOfficer === this.authorizingOfficerFilter || report.item === this.itemFilter);

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(filteredReport);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }
  resetFilters(): void {
    console.log('Filter reset');
    this.organizationFilter = '';
    this.customerFilter = '';
    this.salesPersonFilter = '';
    this.authorizingOfficerFilter = '';
    this.itemFilter = '';


    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(this.reports);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }

}
```

Picture for better understanding
[image: Picture for better understanding]

Comment: `executeFilters` uses `||`, not `&&`. I thought you wanted to use an AND condition...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've said you want to use an AND condition but that when you do and not all filters have values, everything is filtered out. I assume you had an `&&` version of your function (in the question you still have `||`).

You need to check whether you have a value for the filter before applying it:

```
const filteredReport = this.reports.filter(report =>
  (!this.organizationFilter || report.organization === this.organizationFilter) &&
  (!this.customerFilter || report.customer === this.customerFilter) &&
  (!this.salesPersonFilter || report.salesPerson === this.salesPersonFilter) &&
  (!this.itemFilter || report.item === this.itemFilter) &&
  (!this.authorizingOfficerFilter || report.authorizingOfficer === this.authorizingOfficerFilter) &&
  (!this.itemFilter || report.item === this.itemFilter)
);
```

Each criterion in that list is in the form:

```
(!fieldFilterValue || report.field === fieldFilterValue)
```

...meaning that the report will match if either A) there isn't a `fieldFilterValue` (e.g., it's falsy) **or** B) there is one and the report matches it.

They're then all joined together with `&&` so the overall filter is an AND filter.

Note that the falsy check (`!fieldFilterValue`) may or may not be appropriate for all your fields, so tweak it if necessary. For instance, if you had a field that was numeric and you wanted to search for reports where that number field had the value `0`, the code above wouldn't work. In that case, you could use `null` as the value for `fieldFilterValue` when that filter isn't being used, and adjust the code above to:

```
const filteredReport = this.reports.filter(report =>
  (this.organizationFilter === null || report.organization === this.organizationFilter) &&
  (this.customerFilter === null || report.customer === this.customerFilter) &&
  (this.salesPersonFilter === null || report.salesPerson === this.salesPersonFilter) &&
  (this.itemFilter === null || report.item === this.itemFilter) &&
  (this.authorizingOfficerFilter === null || report.authorizingOfficer === this.authorizingOfficerFilter) &&
  (this.itemFilter === null || report.item === this.itemFilter)
);
```

---

Side note: I'd be tempted to avoid having a long list of filters like that, by having a `filters` object instead of individual `organizationFilter`, `customerFilter`, etc. properties:

```
this.filters = {
  organization: null,
  customer: null,
  salesPerson: null,
  item: null,
  authorizingOfficer: null,
  item: null,
};
```

and then doing this:

```
const filteredReport = this.reports.filter(report =>
  Object.entries().every(([key, value]) => value === null || report[key] === value)
);
```

The downside of that is that you can't search for `organizationFilter` anymore and find every use of it...

Comment: Worked like a charm && thanks for a detailed explanation

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple filters in stages so you can implement a more complex logic for matching instead of just `===`:

```
const filteredReport = this.reports
    .filter(report => {
        if (!this.organizationFilter) return true // don't filter if blank
        else return report.organization === this.organizationFilter
    })
    .filter(report => {
        if (!this.customerFilter) return true
        else return report.customer === this.customerFilter
    })
    .filter(report => {
        if (!this.salesPerson) return true
        else return report.salesPerson === this.salesPersonFilter
    })
    .filter(report => {
        if (!this.itemFilter) return true
        else return report.item === this.itemFilter
    })
    .filter(report => {
        if (!this.authorizingOfficerFilter) return true
        else return report.authorizingOfficer === this.authorizingOfficerFilter
    });
```

If you're lazy like me you can even do a little metaprogramming and do this in a loop:

```
let filteredReport = this.reports.slice();

[
    'organization',
    'customer',
    'salesPerson',
    'item',
    'authorizingOfficer'

].forEach(attr => {
    filteredReport = filteredReport.filter(report => {
        if (!this[attr + 'Filter']) return true
        else return report[attr] === this[attr + 'Filter']
    });
});
```

Though personally I would at this point rename the filters `this.filters.customer` etc so that the filter code could be much cleaner:

```
        if (!this.filters[attr]) return true
        else return report[attr] === this.filters[attr]
```

Comment: Unlike the near-equivalent with Java streams, this will result in multiple passes through the data (well, the data that survives earlier passes). (Mind you, it would take hundreds of thousands of reports -- or lots and lots of criteria -- for that to matter.) Separately, it doesn't make sense to call `.filter` at all if the thing you're filtering on isn't set and so the callback will always return `true`...

Comment: @T.J.Crowder This technique is much easier to modularize and easier to allow it to handle complex conditions that may not all be identical. I've used this on live code processing tens of thousands of rows and it barely registers to the user. The processing is still sub one second.

Comment: Like I said, it takes a lot of records for it to matter. But FWIW, I don't find it simpler than a simple `&&` expression.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I didn't say simpler. I said easier to modularize. You can easily imagine how to implement each type of filter as a separate module in a separate file. To do it with `&&` you'd have to rewrite the code to something like this but without individual filters (you can imagine just looping through conditions in a single filter).

Answer (score 1):

The following code will solve your issue. It would've been better from the beginning if filter were an object instead of a group of strings. First you need to create an interface outside of the component class:

```
interface Filter{
  organization?: string,
  customer?: string,
  salesPerson?: string,
  item?: string,
  authorizingOfficer?: string
}
```

Then inside your componenet:

```
filters: Filter;

executeFilters(): void {
    let filteredReport = this.reports;
    for(filterKey in this.filters){
        filteredReport = filteredReport.filter(report => this.filters[filterKey] === report[filterKey]);
    }

    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(filteredReport);
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }
```